# Get possible combinations of a list of elements with length 3 in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list[x,y,z] where x,y,z can assume any value from {0,1}. I would like to find all possible combinations like [0,0,0],[1,0,0], [1,1,0],... in Python.
I have seen that similar questions have been asked before but their were slightly different than what I'm trying to achieve.

To clarify: I want to find all **ordered** (by order here I mean the order of elements in a list, not the order in which the possible lists are shown) possible lists of the form [x,y,z] where x,y,z = 0 or 1. So in my objective a list [0,1,0] is not the same as [1,0,0]. Doing this by hand my code should find the following lists:

```
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,0]
[0,1,1]
[1,1,0]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,1]
```

Comment: Give a look at the itertools module, it's all you need https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Are you 100% sure you want *"a selection of objects from a larger collection in no particular order"* (which is how the `combinations` tag defines combinations)? Rather sounds like you want a *product*.

Comment: @KellyBundy the order is important so for me a list [0,1,0] would be different than [1,0,0]

Comment: What kind of "order" are you looking for? Why does [0,1,1] come after [1,0,0]?

Comment: @GinoMempin the order in which the lists appear is not really relevant to me, the order of the elements in a list is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
import itertools

nums = [0,1]

comb = list(itertools.product(nums, repeat=3))
print(comb)
```